# Django Nonetype object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django, django-views

I want create product element and redirect to him page

```
def newprodcreate(request, c_id):
if models.company.objects.get(email = request.user.username).id == int(c_id):
    name = request.POST['newprodname']
    comp = models.company.objects.get(id = int(c_id))
    prod = models.product()
    prod.name = name
    prod.comp_id = int(c_id)
    prod.address = comp.address
    prod.lat = comp.lat
    prod.lng = comp.lng
    prod.phone = comp.phone
    prod.cur_id = 2
    prod.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect("/p/" + str(prod.id))
```

the element created in database, but prod.id is Null

model:

```
class product(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table = "product"
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
crdate = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now())
comp_id = models.IntegerField()
categ = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
img = models.FileField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT +"/product/", max_length=200)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For django models There will be a default field with name "id" which is auto increment field. you have override that id with `IntegerField` that is `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)`

So you have to provide `id` explicitly every time when you create `product object`

Better solution is to change `id`  `IntegerField` to `AutoField`

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Then your id will be created automatically no need to pass id every time you create new object.

Answer (score 2):

Dear michael in django ORM for creating autho field or serial field which used for id primary key or etc we use Autofield instead of integer field .

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

your model in corrected state:
class product(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table = "product"
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
crdate = models.DateTimeField(default =
        datetime.now())
comp_id = models.IntegerField()
categ = models.CharField(max_length=200,     default="")
img =     models.FileField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT.    +"/product/", max_length=200)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)...
```